# Force Close by using Async Task

Tags: android

I want to display a progressdialog when a client sends request to the server..the request should be done in background...but i am getting a force close when i use the AsyncTask..Please help ..Thank you

```
package com.example.client;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static ProgressDialog Dialog;
    String s1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // sendreq();
                new SendUserTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public String sendreq() {
        try {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.7.116",
                    9011);
            Socket serversocket = new Socket();
            serversocket.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
            serversocket.setSoTimeout(10000);

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                    serversocket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
                    serversocket.getInputStream());
            out.flush();
            String msg = "";

            msg = "hi";
            out.writeBytes(msg);
            out.flush();
            byte[] message = new byte[100];
            in.read(message);
            s1 = new String(message);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(s1);
            in.close();
            out.close();
            serversocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(e),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class SendUserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Logging In....", true);

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            if (Dialog.isShowing())
                Dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                return sendreq();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(e),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(s1);` is executed from the background thread. you cannot access UI elements outside the UI thread.

You need to move that part to either onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute, or to run it in a runOnUiThread Runnable.

Comment: well i dont think thats the problem...coz instead of calling the mtd sendreq() using AsyncTask...if i just call it directly by onClick(one that i hve commented) it works fine...

Comment: @user1729085 yes, that is the point he is making.  When the parts within `sendreq()` that manipulate the UI are called from the UI thread, they work ok.  When they are called from a background thread in the `AsyncTask` then they fail.  So as @njzk2 says, you need to perform your UI manipulation in one of the methods that can access the UI.

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackgorund()` is a **non-UI thread** and you cannot access UI elements inside it. The code inside doInBackground() runs on a separate non-ui thread which does not have access to the UI elements defined in your layout. Also, since you are calling another Activity via intents, you should always keep in mind that an Activity runs on the UI thread and hence you should never start another Activity from inside a non-ui thread.

So, remove the code " **`((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(s1);`** " accessing the UI elements from inside of doInBackground() and instead put it inside **`onPostExecute()`**, which is a UI thread and is called after doInBackground() finishes the background processing.

Comment: ya you were right.....i had to remove both the settext and also the toast...from the sendreq() and had to put it in the postexec...works fine now.....but does that mean i cant access any of the elemnts from the UI thread? or is there a way to do it????

Comment: sorry i mean from the non UI thread....is there a way to access UI elements from the doInBackground mtd???

Comment: No, I dont think you can do that. You cannot access UI elements from the background thread. You can however use onProgressUpdate() to access the UI as your task executes.

Comment: `runOnUiThread Runnable` is another option, but I would prefer using the `onProgressUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... After googling a lot i finally came to understand that you cant access UI elements from main thread into a new non-UI thread....So you cant use elements like textview or even getApplicationContext mtd tht v use for toast in the dobackground mtd or even in anyother mts that the dobackground is calling....This also applies for the new Thread() using runnable..Thank you njzk2 for your help :)